# Please relocate the Community User back to the server from Brazil

Tags: bug, status-completed

[image]

Please relocate the Community User back to the server from Brazil.

Comment: LoL!, @Shog9. Did you just make Community user naturalize to Brazil, instead of taking him back?

Comment: Hey, I *tried* to talk him into coming back, but... He just stared at me like I was crazy, muttered, "as meninas!", and disappeared into the night. 'e's gone native, I tell ya...

Comment: What was the previous location?

Comment: Community User was once an Introspective Socialist @bav

Comment: @Shog9 */me points to the **other** non-MSO community users*

Comment: So [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade) proves reputation is no currency, or is the exchange rate 1 tot 1? (And how does (s)he travel without being seen?)

Comment: This is by design. It's in sync with company philosophy. http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/51603#51603

Comment: Speaking of Brazil, have a look at this: http://pics.kuvaton.com/kuvei/mt_roraima.jpg

Comment: Oh noes @Pekka, I have Acrophobia!

Comment: @YOU me too! The first thing I thought when I saw the photo was the edge and how easy it would be to fall off. But would be a *fascinating* thing to go there. I wonder how, other than by helicopter, people get up there (if at all).

Comment: Ah, there is a natural "ramp". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Roraima

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oops? This is now complete, all is well with our beloved Community user (on all sites) again.

Comment: For a moment I guessed you might have added that as an official location? [Too bad](http://i.imgur.com/QeWqj.png) ;-)